# PageUp/PageDown in Length Page with 10000 records in Gridview in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I implement scroll up or scroll down functionalities when I am having 10000 of records in single page.

I have to keep 2 buttons(btnUp and btnDown) on basic webform page and when they click on these buttons the page should scroll up until every 1000 records. For instance if i have 10000 records in single page, and when i clicked on btnDown, it should scroll till 1000 records down, again when i keep clicking again btnDown it should scroll like 2000, 3000, 4000 and so on.

Please suggest how can i do this.

Comment: any reason for not setting [PageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx) to 1000 and [AllowPaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx) to true

Comment: No the requirement is to show all records in one page. do not need for paging

Comment: I question the need for any page element to have 10000 entries. It's a completely useless ux.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use the JavaScript `window.scrollTo()` function, like this:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    ' Call this function in response to up or down button click
    function setScroll(thresholdCount) {
        // Get grid view

        // Loop through rows

        // Check when row count equals threshold (1000, 2000, 3000, etc.)

        // When threshold found, scroll to that DOM element
        window.scrollTo(element);
    }
</script>
```

Read [Dynamically Scroll to Gridview Row in Asp.Net](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1321/dynamically-scroll-to-gridview-row-in-aspnet) for a start at implementing this type of behavior.